# how to get the List/Record type script parameter's text value in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I am setting a List/Record type script parameter and Select one value (Display name: Sample Company, Id: 5) as a default. I'm using

```
nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT','custscript_my_parameter');
```

to get the value. it returns the id(in my case 5) of the `List/Record`. But I need the display name(in my case Sample Company) of the `List/Record`. Anyone, Please advice to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create another script parameter of type `Free-Form Text` and set the display value for the field to retrieve on the other side. You could use something like below

```
nlapiGetContext().getSetting('SCRIPT','custscript_my_parameter_text');
```

Otherwise if you want to get the display value with the id you have then, you probably need to load the record and get the company name(text).

Comment: This appears to be the easiest method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the documentation of `nlobjContext#getSetting`, I do not see a way for you to get the text value of the select field. It looks like you will need to retrieve the ID from the script setting, then perform an `nlapiLookupField` on the appropriate record to retrieve the appropriate text value.